# Colorbox next and previous not showing?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I just can't get next and previous to show on my colorbox, for some reason it doesn't realise I'm sending in a group, is there something obvious I'm missing? I've checked the JS variable has values ETC :/

```
<ul class="items-big self-clear">
<li class="selected">
<a href="/media/1373/deck_and_table_Large landscape.jpg" class="cboxElement">
<img title="Deck and chairs keep my beers warm" src="/media/1373/deck_and_table_Medium landscape.jpg">
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/media/1473/shower_Large landscape.jpg" class="cboxElement">
<img title="" src="/media/1473/shower_Medium landscape.jpg">
</a>
</li>
</ul>

$itemsBig = $('.items-big'),
$itemsBig.find('a').colorbox({
  transition: "elastic",
  close: "Close",
  initialWidth: 1,
  initialHeight: 1,
  title: function () { return $(this).find("img").attr('title'); }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use colorbox's rel property to indicate that those links should be shown together as a group.

```
$itemsBig.find('a').colorbox({
  rel:"landscapes",
  transition: "elastic",
  close: "Close",
  initialWidth: 1,
  initialHeight: 1,
  title: function () { return $(this).find("img").attr('title'); }
});
```